# How to return a reply from json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i would like tu save a record into my db MySql with ajax.

I have a button into my Page, that call a method in javascript. THe method javascript with jSON call a page in PHP for write a record into my DB.

Now the record is write on DB but i  can not read the answer. I would like if the record is write on the that method return "OK", if the record is not write into DB the method retunr me "KO".

This is my code javascript:

```
function saveRiga(){

    var codiceBarre = document.getElementById("codiceBarre").value;
    var nome = document.getElementById("nomeArticolo").value;


    var quantita=document.getElementById("quantita").value;
    if(quantita == "" || quantita ==null){
        alert("Campo quantitÃ  Obbligatorio");
        return;
    }

    if(isNumeric(quantita)){
        var idOrdine =69;
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j.getJSON('salvaArticoliOrdine.php', {codiceBarre: codiceBarre, nome: nome, quantita: quantita, idOrdine: idOrdine, nomeMetodo: 'salva'}, function(data) {

            document.getElementById("codiceBarre2").value="ciccio";
        $j.each(data,function(i,item){
            alert(item);
            alert(i);   
        });
        });

    }else{
        alert("Inserire solo numeri interi positivi");
        return;
    }
}
```

This is a code PHP

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['codiceBarre']) && isset($_REQUEST['nome']) && isset($_REQUEST['quantita']) ) { 

    $codiceBarre = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['codiceBarre'])); 
    $nomeArticolo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['nome'])); 
    $quantita = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['quantita'])); 
    $ultimo_id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['idOrdine'])); 
    $nomeMetodo= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['nomeMetodo'])); 
    if($nomeMetodo == 'salva'){
        $query = "INSERT INTO DETTORDINI (CODIORDINE,CODICEART,NOMEARTICOLO,QUANTITA,PREZZOCAD,PREZZOTOT) VALUES (".$ultimo_id.",'".$codiceBarre."','".$nomeArticolo."',".$quantita.",0,0);";
         mysql_query($query);
        if (!$query) {
            echo json_encode("Nessun risultato disponibile");
        }else{
            $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
            echo json_encode($arr);
             //echo json_encode($ultimo_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: `echo json_encode(array('error' => "Nessun risultato disponibile"));`

Comment: try setting you page response header to `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
if (!$query) {
    echo json_encode("Nessun risultato disponibile");
 }else{
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    //echo json_encode($ultimo_id);
 }
```

by this:

```
 if (mysql_affected_rows()<=0) {
    echo json_encode("Nessun risultato disponibile");
 }else{
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    //echo json_encode($ultimo_id);
 }
```

this way you'll be testing if a row was really inserted or not...

Comment: Ok i have replace your code but i think the problem is in this code 

    $j.getJSON('salvaArticoliOrdine.php', {codiceBarre: codiceBarre, nome: nome, quantita: quantita, idOrdine: idOrdine, nomeMetodo: 'salva'}, function(data) {
    
                document.getElementById("codiceBarre2").value="ciccio";
            $j.each(data,function(i,item){
                alert(item);
                alert(i);   
            });
            });

because i don't see the value "ciccio" in text box and i don't see the alert.
Where is my problem?

Comment: replace this: echo json_encode("Nessun risultato disponibile"); by this: echo json_encode(array('error' => "Nessun risultato disponibile")); as @Robert mentioned up there in the comments. Second thing make sure your isNumeric function is defined. if yes check your console for javascript errors.